# DateTime.Now value differs based on Android devices

Tags: c#, android, datetime, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin Android Project.  In my project
`DateTime.Now` Method returns value differently based on Android OS

For Android OS = 4.0.4 Following is the value of DateTime.Now

> **DateTime.Now** {15/09/2015 14:41:26}

For Android OS > 4.0.4 Following is the value of DateTime.Now

> **DateTime.Now** {9/15/2015 2:41:26 PM}

This causes issue because, below is my validation

```
Convert.ToDateTime("9/16/2017 12:16:00 PM") > DateTime.Now)
```

I am perplexed with the issue.  The validation will work only for Android OS > 4.0.4. Any help would be appreciable!

**My tried outs:**
1. Tried to convert the DateTime as follows

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

However, It is returning value as ""9/16/2015 12:16:00 pm"".  It doesn't helps me to fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be caused by different default Locale on the devices.

The following should work independent of the default Locale

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
Convert.ToDateTime("9/16/2017 12:16:00 PM", enUS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(string dateTime)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTime))
        return (DateTime?)null;

    var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    var formats = new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "M-d-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "MM-dd-yyyy", "M.d.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy" }
            .Union(ci.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()).ToArray();
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.None);

    return dt;
}
```

Then convert it to format you want,

```
var stringDate = myDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```